# Virtualbox has no more network access when Cloudflare Warp VPN 2022.5.226.0 is active

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, cloudflare

I have been using the Cloudflare Warp VPN (also known as 1.1.1.1) on Windows 10 Pro and Home for years. On these Windows machines (all fully updated), I have VirtualBox (6.1.34) installed, and run multiple virtual boxes in parallel on each machine.

On May/25, 2022, Cloudflare Warp released the new version **2022.5.226.0**.
After installing this version on the host machines, all my existing **virtual machines can no longer access the internet**. They all report 'can access your local network, but cannot access the internet'.
Troubleshooting I tried:

- when I switch the Warp/VPN off, everything works immediately fine
- resetting or reinstalling the networks settings, adapters, etc., inside the virtual machine does not help
- using another (virtual) network adapter does not help
- newly created virtual machines (all Windows 10) have the same issue
- when I downgrade Cloudflare Warp (back to 2022.4.115.0), it works immediately again

To me this looks like the Cloudflare Warp update breaks VirtualBox network access.

Does anyone have the same problem, ***and knows how to fix it?***
Is there some setting or reset or whatever I didn't find?

Answer (score 1):

Super frustrated by the same thing.  As far as I can make out, the fix is to [install cloudflare warp](https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux/) directly on the vm (which appears not to have a headless login method).

The problem with piggy-backing on the windows instance of cloudflare-warp is that it sets itself up on loopback, and from my quick investigation, the VB instance can't route to that listener.  There may be another path to success in fixing that route/connection issue.  I'll keep poking at this and will try to remember to update here if I find a fix.

---

I came up with a working solution. After trying for a while to get Cloudflare Warp working on the vm, I gave up and tried another tack. I installed a DNS proxy on windows (specifically, [Acrylic DNS Proxy](https://mayakron.altervista.org/)), and configured it to use the Warp listeners for its primary and secondary forwarders:

```
PrimaryServerAddress=127.0.2.2
SecondaryServerAddress=127.0.2.3
```

By default, it then listens on UDP(53) on all non-loopback interfaces, which gives the VM somewhere to land its request, and returns responses as resolved by Warp. It has worked pretty solidly for me for a few months.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on reg ole Win 10. Used warp for years and around the same time only the 1.1.1.1 setting works.

Can confirm version 2022.4.115.0 still works. Previous versions can be found here.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-devices/warp/download-warp/

redirects you to here

https://install.appcenter.ms/orgs/cloudflare/apps/1.1.1.1-windows-1/distribution_groups/release

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240831)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).