# Sharing Cloudflare Warp over ethernet?

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup a Cloudflare Warp connection for a device that doesn't have a suitable Warp client for it. My solution is to use a PC to host the Warp client and share the Warp connection via a second ethernet adapter.

On windows I was able to get the sharing working on physical connections, e.g. sharing Wifi connection to ethernet. But so far I can use the same method to share the Warp connection.

[image: windows sharing center]

Is there anything special that needs to be configured for Warp? With some other VPN services it was a lot easier. Some could share the VPN connection simply by turning on the mobile hot-spot on the host PC. But that's not the case for Warp.

related: [Virtualbox has no more network access when Cloudflare Warp VPN 2022.5.226.0 is active](https://superuser.com/questions/1723409/virtualbox-has-no-more-network-access-when-cloudflare-warp-vpn-2022-5-226-0-is-a)